# Is there an alternative method in C++ to calculate the area between two angles on a polar curve (exprtk library doesn't work)?

Tags: c++, calculation, area

I'm currently working on a project in C++ to calculate the area between two angles on a polar curve. I tried using the exprtk library, but unfortunately it doesn't  work.
I would like to explore an alternative library or method that can compute the area between two angles on a polar curve in C++.If you have any recommendations or suggestions, I would greatly appreciate it.

I tried to use the exprtk library in C++ to calculate the area between two angles on a polar curve. But i encountered difficulties with the installation process.

Comment: The installation issues with exprtk are surely their own question. I know nothing about that library but why don't you ask that separately, with a transcript of the installation session, the errors etc.

Comment: Just (1/2)Integral(r^2.d theta ), with the integration done numerically (e.g. Simpson's rule).

Comment: @lastchance please 'promote' your comment to an answer, and maybe if you know a way to implement Simpson's rule or have a link, that might be nice.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you could compute the area as

```
const double PI = 3.14159;
double circle_area = PI * radius * radius;  // total area of circle
double angle_diff = polar2 - polar1;  // difference in polar angles in radians

double area_between = circle_area * (angle_diff / (2*PI));
```

This is just a simple ratio based on the total circle area. For example if your two angles were `0` and `PI` then the area would just be of a semi-circle so it would be half the area of the full circle.

Comment: I think this assumes the polar curve is completely circular, if that is the case this computation works correctly as far as I can tell.  However, pleaser see the comment by lastchance on the original post.

Comment: Oh I see, the question may be about some arbitrary curve, not just a segment along a circle's perimeter?

Comment: That's my interpretation

Comment: To find the area of a region in polar coordinates defined by the equation r = f(θ) with α ≤ θ ≤ β, you can use the integral A = 1 2∫ β α [f(θ)]2dθ1.To find the area between two curves in the polar coordinate system, you can subtract the area inside the inner curve from the area inside the outer curve2. If f(θ) ≥ g(θ), this means 1 2∫b af(θ)2 − g(θ)2dθ2. -- SOURCE:  Microsoft bing

Answer (score 0):

OK, I was asked to promote a comment to an answer, so here goes.

Mathematically, the area is Integral( (1/2) r<sup>2</sup> d theta ) for a polar curve r=f(theta), where r is radius and theta is angle from a fixed line in radians.

In many cases (e.g. with own maths, Mathematica, Maple or whatever) you can do the integration analytically. Otherwise, you can do it with your favourite numerical integrator. The code below just uses Simpson's rule and isn't very clever.

I've tried to make the code reasonably general, so just define your polar curve with a lambda function of theta and set "polar" equal to it. Another lambda function, half_r_squared (read it quickly!) is then sent to the integrator.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

const double PI = 4.0 * atan( 1.0 );

//======================================================================

double Simpson( double a, double b, int n, function<double(double)> f )   // a < b; n even and >= 2
{
   double dx = ( b - a ) / n;
   double I = f( a ) + f( b );
   for ( int i = 1; i < n; i += 2 ) I += 4.0 * f( a + i * dx );
   for ( int i = 2; i < n; i += 2 ) I += 2.0 * f( a + i * dx );
   return I *= dx / 3.0;
}

//======================================================================

int main()
{
   auto cardioid = []( double theta ){ return 0.5 * ( 1.0 - cos( theta ) ); };
   auto circle   = []( double theta ){ return 1.0; };

// auto polar = circle;                // take your choice
   auto polar = cardioid;
   auto half_r_squared = [ polar ]( double theta ){ double r = polar( theta );   return 0.5 * r * r; };

   double deg1 = 0.0;
   double deg2 = 90.0;
   int n = 1000;

   double rad1 = deg1 * PI / 180.0;
   double rad2 = deg2 * PI / 180.0;
   cout << "Area from " << deg1 << " degrees to " << deg2 << " degrees is " << Simpson( rad1, rad2, n, half_r_squared ) << '\n';
}

//======================================================================
```

Output for a cardioid is

```
Area from 0 degrees to 90 degrees is 0.0445243
```

The exact answer (for those angles and the particular cardioid give in the code) would be (1/8)*(3.PI/4-2), which gives the same 6 sig. fig. answer.